# Spring boot - scan packages

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am starting to write an application in spring boot and below is how my package structure looks:

```
com.practice.spring.project.helloworld.HelloworldApplication.java
com.practice.spring.project.repository.EmployeeRepository.java
com.practice.spring.project.model.Employee.java
```

Below is how i had my application startup successfully,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.practice.spring.project.DB", basePackageClasses = InitDatabase.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.practice.spring.project.repository" , basePackageClasses = EmployeeRepository.class)
public class HelloworldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(HelloworldApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) throws Exception {
        return (args) -> {
            System.out.println("Calling it after the application context is all loaded up");
            employeeRepository.save(new Employee("Ashwin", "Architect"));
        };

    }
}
```

My question is should I have to specify the base-packages & baseClasses for every class I add ? It would be tough if have 10 packages having 10 different classes.

Am sure there should be an easier way to scan and instantiate classes in different package.

Comment: If you would put class `HelloworldApplication` in a package at the base, for example in `com.practice.spring.project`, or make the other packages subpackages of the package that contains class `HelloworldApplication`, then it would all work automatically and you would not need the `@ComponentScan` annotation at all, neither the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation.

Answer (score -1):

Figured out a way - set the basePackages to com.practice.spring.project.*

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.practice.spring.project.*")
```